# What is the sum of the reciprocal of primes? (Yes, it diverges..)

Tags: number-theory

It's well known that the summation over 1/p diverges just as 1/n does. However, in the case of the sum of 1/n, we can establish upper and lower bounds to the sum with the integrals over 1/n and 1/(n-1). Therefore we can say that the sum is asymptotically equal to ln(x). Can we do anything similar for the sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers?

I suspect there isn't a neat function due to the unpredictable distribution of prime numbers.

Comment: The sum $\Sigma 1/p$ over primes $p\leq n$ is asymptotic to $\ln \ln n$.

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate, as pointed out by @GerryMyerson.

Comment: **Not a duplicate.** This question is a specific elaboration on the linked question. It's not about _whether_ the sum converges, it's about _how it diverges._ Suggested addition to the title:  "Yes it diverges, but how?" And if there were room and patience:  "Is the finite sum asymptotic to some closed-form function?" The point is, anyone googling 'sum reciprocal primes' should be led to the Meissel–Mertens constant. This question does that. The linked question does not, nor should it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using $\pi(k)=\frac{k}{\log(k)}\left(1+O\left(\frac1{\log(k)}\right)\right)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\le n}\frac1p
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\pi(k)-\pi(k-1)}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\pi(k)}{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\pi(k)}{k+1}\\
&=\frac{\pi(n)}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\pi(k)}{k(k+1)}\\
&=\frac{\pi(n)}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\pi(k)}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\pi(k)}{k^2(k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\frac{\pi(k)}{k^2}+O(1)\\
&=\sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\left[\frac1{k\log(k)}+O\left(\frac1{k\log(k)^2}\right)\right]+O(1)\\[9pt]
&=\log(\log(n))+O(1)
\end{align}
$$
where we bound the sum by $\int_2^{n-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\log(x)}$ and $\int_3^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\log(x)}$ in the last step.

In fact,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{p\le n}\frac1p-\log(\log(n))\right)=M
$$
where $M$ is the [Meissel–Mertens constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant).

Comment: @BalarkaSen: no bigger than Taylor Series, really, and quite useful. However, for this sum, we could bound by integrals.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: I did use summation by parts at the beginning, or did you mean to sum $\frac1{k\log(k)}$?

Comment: So the [surreal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) answer would be $log(log(\omega)) + M$ as it were?