# Is the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{j}}$ where $p_{j}$ is the $j$th prime convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Does the series $\sum_{n=1 }^{\infty}1/p_{j} $ of  reciprocal primes converge?

Experimentally, it seems convergent.

Comment: Look up Mertens' second theorem.  It grows like $\log\log n$

Comment: How can a sum of positive numbers go to $0$ when the sequence of partial sums is positive and increasing?

Comment: Do you mean *the* sequence of primes? If you can specify $(p_j)$ arbitrarily, you can certainly make this convergent.

Comment: I mean the sequence of reciprocal primes.

Comment: Don't confuse sequences and series. Sequences are $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$. Series are the sum of these terms: $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots$.

Comment: So it diverges according to Merten's second theorem?

Comment: @MichaelT: My gross typo, thanks. Was typing rushingly. :)

Comment: Yes, it diverges according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems

Comment: Let $p_j$ be the $j$-th prime. The fact that $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{p_j}$ diverges was proved by Euler. The divergence is *slow*. Even a quite lengthy computation will give results that look consistent with convergence.

Comment: Asking if it is convergent is reasonable. Asking if it tends to 0 is less reasonable.

Comment: @almagest: Then how does it have anything to with "off-topic"? Are you ...

Comment: I didn't say or imply it was off-topic. But it would have been good if you could have taken a little more trouble drafting your question!

Comment: @Comeseeconquer. +1 Thank you.

Comment: This is actually how Euler proves there are infinitely many primes. He does it by introducing what's now called the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, and using the fact that it has a pole at $s=1$ to show $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$ diverges. If there were finitely many primes it would be a finite sum, and it would converge. This is the beginning of analytic number theory.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Yes, are you disagreeing with something I said? If you take the log of $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ and expand $-\log (1-p^{-s}) = \frac{1}{p^s} + \frac{1}{p^{2s}} + \cdots$, you can write $\log \zeta(s) = \sum_p \sum_n \frac{1}{p^{ns}}$. You split the double sum into $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}$ plus everything else, and you show everything else converges, so $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}$ diverges as $s \rightarrow 1^+$, because $\zeta(s)$ does. Therefore the sum $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}$ must be infinite. This is the form I've always seen the argument in when the details were provided.

Comment: Ok, granted. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674877/what-is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-primes-yes-it-diverges

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an easy proof of the divergence of the series of prime reciprocals, which I saw in the *American Mathematical Monthly* in a bygone millennium. Assume for a contradiction that the series converges. Choose $N$ so that
$$\frac1{P_{N+1}}+\frac1{P_{N+2}}+\cdots\lt1.$$
Then
$$S=1+\left(\frac1{P_{N+1}}+\frac1{P_{N+2}}+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac1{P_{N+1}}+\frac1{P_{N+2}}+\cdots\right)^2+\cdots$$
is a convergent geometric series.

Let $d=P_1P_2\cdots P_N$ and consider the series
$$\frac11+\frac1{1+d}+\frac1{1+2d}+\frac1{1+3d}+\cdots$$
which of course diverges. However, each denominator $1+nd$, since it is not divisible by any of the first $N$ primes (note the resemblance to Euclid's proof), is a product of primes $\ge P_{N+1}$. Thus each term $\frac1{1+nd}$ occurs in the geometric series $S$ when the powers are expanded, that is,
$$\frac11+\frac1{1+d}+\frac1{1+2d}+\cdots\lt1+\left(\frac1{P_{N+1}}+\frac1{P_{N+2}}+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac1{P_{N+1}}+\cdots\right)^2+\cdots\lt\infty$$
and this contradiction proves the theorem.

**If anyone reading this knows the source of this proof, please edit the attribution into my answer. Thanks.**

The proof is given by Clarkson [Clarkson, James A. ( 1966) On the series of prime reciprocals. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc .. /7: 541; MR 32. #5573.]
https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-02/S0002-9939-1966-0188132-7/S0002-9939-1966-0188132-7.pdf

Comment: +1: I've never seen this argument before. Nice and simple.

Comment: @Riemann Many thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674909), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{\substack{p\le n\\p\text{ prime}}}\frac1p=\log(\log(n))+O(1)
$$
and therefore, the sum diverges.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment? This seems to answer the question, so would I think it's somewhat helpful. I referenced the other answer so that I would not need to duplicate the other answer here.