# About $\sum_{p \in \mathbb P}^{ }\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}\left(p,p+1\right)}$

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Consider the following summation:

> $$\sum_{p \in \mathbb P}^{ }\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}\left(p,p+1\right)}$$

Where $\mathbb P$ is the set of prime numbers.

The summation is bounded since:

$$\sum_{p \in \mathbb P}^{ }\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}\left(p,p+1\right)}<\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}\left(k,k+1\right)}<\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}\left(k,k^{2}\right)}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-1≈ 0.644934066848$$

Which follows from the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

My question is
what is the asymptotic  behavior of this summation? is there any better upper bound?

Comment: Well, clearly, $\text{lcm}(p,p+1) = p(p+1)$, so your sum is equivalent to, after partial fraction decomposition,

$$\sum_{p \in \Bbb P} \frac 1 p - \frac 1 {p+1}$$

The sum $\sum 1 / p$ is known to be asymptotic to $\log \log n$. More explicitly, per [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674877/what-is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-primes-yes-it-diverges),

$$\sum_{p \in \Bbb P \\ p \le n} \frac 1 p = \log \log n + \mathcal O(1)$$

[cont.]

Comment: and, in a vein similar to the harmonic series, there exists [a constant $M \approx 0.261497$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant) such that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{p \in \Bbb P \\ p \le n} \frac 1 p - \log \log n \right) = M$$

I'm not 100% sure how this might be useful yet, I'm a bit lost in applying it, but it's a start.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer, WOW, Indeed I did not know about that constant, really thanks.

Comment: You have $\operatorname{lcm}(n, n + 1) = n (n + 1) / \gcd(n, n + 1) = n (n + 1)$....

Comment: [A179119](http://oeis.org/A179119) in the OEIS gives the corresponding numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, $\operatorname{lcm}(p,p+1)=p(p+1)$ for $p$ prime. Contrary to what has been written in the comments, the sum converges since the terms are $O\left(p^{-2}\right)$; the series cannot be split into separate sums using partial fraction decomposition because the terms of the individual sums would be $O\left(p^{-1}\right)$, so these sums don’t converge individually.

We have

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_p\frac1{p(p+1)}
&=&
\sum_p\frac1{p^2}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac1p}
\\
&=&
\sum_p\sum_{s=2}(-1)^sp^{-s}
\\
&=&
\sum_{s=2}(-1)^s\sum_pp^{-s}
\\
&=&
\sum_{s=2}(-1)^sP(s)\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where $P(s)$ is the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function). Wolfram|Alpha [evaluates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20PrimeZeta%28s%29%20%28-1.0%29%5Es%20for%20s%3D2..infinity) this sum to approximately $0.33023$.